# How to avoid this error when redefining `\psgrid` to be `\relax`?

Tags: pstricks

## Scenario

`\pspicture` with `showgrid` will be regarded as a **PERMANENT** grid.

`\psgrid` in `\pspicture` **WITHOUT** `showgrid` will be regarded as a **TEMPORARY** grid.

If I want to remove all temporary grids, I just need to redefine `\psgrid` as follows in the preamble.

```
\let\psgrid\relax
```

However, if I do this, the `\pspicture` with `showgrid` will produce strange output.

---

## Question

How to resolve this issue?

---

## Minimal Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

%If I uncomment out this, 
%all temporary grids must disappear.
%\let\psgrid\relax

\begin{document}

%permanent grid
\pspicture[showgrid](2,2)
\psframe*(1,1)
\endpspicture


%temporary grid
\pspicture(2,2)
\psgrid
\psframe*(1,1)
\endpspicture

\end{document}
```

Comment: I already gave you an answer how to deal with two macros.you can't say `\let\foo\relax` when `foo` expects some optional parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeatletter
\def\psgrid@iv(#1)(#2)(#3){}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\pspicture[showgrid](2,2)
\psframe*(1,1)
\endpspicture

\pspicture(2,2)
\psgrid
\psframe*(1,1)
\endpspicture

\end{document}
```

Comment: @xport: see changed code

Comment: @xport: then you have to copy _all_ `\psgrid` commands (see pstricks.tex) to won macros and use this for a permanent grid.

Comment: Why cannot we use `\psset{showgrid=true/false/top/bottom}` at the preamble?